# Why is a template with deduced return type not overloadable with other versions of it?

Tags: c++, c++14, overloading, auto

Why are the following two templates incompatible and can't be overloaded?

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
auto f(T t) { return t.size(); }
template<typename T>
auto f(T t) { return t.foobar(); }

int main() {
   f(std::vector<int>());   
}
```

I would think they are (more or less) equivalent with the following which compiles fine (as we cannot do `decltype auto(t.size())` I can't give an exact equivalent without some noise..).

```
template<typename T>
auto f(T t) -> decltype(t.size() /* plus some decay */) { return t.size(); }

template<typename T>
auto f(T t) -> decltype(t.foobar() /* plus some decay */) { return t.foobar(); }
```

Clang and GCC complain `main.cpp:6:16: error: redefinition of 'f'` if I leave off the trailing return type, however.

<sub>(Note that I am not seeking for the place in the Standard which defines this behavior - which you may include in your answer too, if you wish - but for an explanation of why this behavior is desirable or status-quo).</sub>

Comment: you cannot overload a function on its returned type, thus they have actually the same prototype from the point of view of the compiler and because of that you got the *redefinition* error.

Comment: @skypjack You can overload function templates on return type.

Comment: @skypjack That's completely irrelevant for function templates, which you can overload on the return type (it's part of their signature).

Comment: What is the type return type from f.foobar() please add definition?

Comment: @g24l the dependent return type of a "foobar" function call on a variable which has the dependent type of `T`, which is clearly different from the type of `t.size()`. Consider my second example codeblock, which is wellformed.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki ok got it now!

Comment: my best guess would be that they didn't want to define an equivalence relation on a function template's body (and they would need to mangle it). Simply comparing two expressions that appear in a `return` is not enough, it may depend on the code before it in the template.. but I'm not sure..

Comment: @Columbo you are right indeed, my fault, sorry.

Comment: this weird , I get no error when I compile this in c++11 , sorry but no c++14 compiler here.

Comment: @g24l, He said the second snippet compiles fine.

Comment: Can you expand on what makes you think they are equivalent or, in other words, why this should be allowed/useful?

Comment: @black i think they are "more or less" equivalent because the rationale of introducing deduced return types was to avoid repeating the expression in both the trailing return type and the function body. If now there are still cases where you have to repeat the type, the replacement isn't really 100%, and worth documenting by someone in a SO question. If you know the reason please create an answer. It is useful whereever the SFINAE done when the trailing return type is present is useful.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb wouldn't that require to parse the body of the function to verify the function signature? How should one do without?

Comment: @g24l I think it would require that. I wasn't sure whether there were other reasons to have it this way, apart from that. Hopefully the question helps also others who wonder about this aswell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *deduced* return type can clearly not be part of the signature.
However, inferring an expression that determines the return type (and participates in SFINAE) from `return` statements has some issues. Let's say we were to take the first `return` statement's expression and paste it into some adjusted, virtual trailing-return-type:

1. What if the **returned expression depends on *local* declarations**? This isn't necessarily stopping us, but it snarls the rules tremendously. Don't forget that we can't use the names of the entities declared; This could potentially complex our trailing-return-type sky-high for potentially no benefit at all.
2. A popular use case of this feature are function templates returning **lambdas**. However, we can hardly make a lambda part of the signature - the complications that would arise have been elaborated on in great detail before. Mangling alone would require heroic efforts. Hence we'd have to exclude function templates using lambdas.
3. The **signature** of a declaration couldn't be determined if it wasn't a definition also, introducing a whole set of other problems. The easiest solution would be to disallow (non-defining) declarations of such function templates entirely, which is almost ridiculous.

Fortunately the author of N3386 strove to keep the rules (and implementation!) simple. I can't imagine how not having to write a trailing-return-type yourself in some corner cases warrants such meticulous rules.

Comment: Nice answer . I think I will accept. A solution perhaps would be to allow a function template (or function in general) be assigned an expression as result? `template<typename T> auto f(T t) = t.size();`.

Comment: Well, we can easily *force* a lambda into a signature, using `decltype` or template-deduction.

Comment: @Deduplicator How? (Btw., we're talking about the lambda(-expression), not the closure type)

Comment: Ok, if you mean the defining expression instead of the type, yes, that won't be part of the signature.

Answer (score 1):

I think that may be commitee miss but backstory I believe is the following:

1. You cannot overload over the function return type. This means that in declaration

   ```
   template<typename T>
   auto f(T t) { return t.size(); }
   ```

   Value of `auto` is not interesting to compiler in fact until function instantiation. Obviously compiller does not add some SFINAE check to the function body to check if `T::size` exist as it does not in all other cases when `T` is used inside function body
2. When generating overloads compiler will check if two function signatures are exact equivalent taking in mind all possible substitutions.

   In the first case then compiler will get smth like

   ```
   [template typename T] f(T)
   [template typename T] f(T)
   ```

   That are exact equivalent

   In the second case however as `decltype` specified explicitly it will be added to the template arguments so you'll get

   ```
   [template typename T, typename = typeof(T::size())] f(T)
   [template typename T, typename = typeof(T::size())] f(T)
   ```

   That are not exact equivalents obviously.

   So compiler will refuse the first case while second *could be* OK when substituting real type instead of `T`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the symbols created by my compiler:

```
[tej@archivbox ~]$ cat test1.cc

#include <vector>

template<typename T>
auto JSchaubStackOverflow(T t) { return t.size(); }

// template<typename T>
// auto f(T t) { return t.foobar(); }

int do_something() {
       JSchaubStackOverflow(std::vector<int>());
       return 4;
}
[tej@archivbox ~]$ c++ -std=c++14 -pedantic test1.cc -c -o test1.o
[tej@archivbox ~]$ nm test1.o | grep JScha
0000000000000000 W _Z20JSchaubStackOverflowISt6vectorIiSaIiEEEDaT_
[tej@archivbox ~]$ nm -C test1.o | grep JScha
0000000000000000 W auto JSchaubStackOverflow<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >)
[tej@archivbox ~]$ cat test2.cc

#include <vector>

template<typename T>
auto JSchaubStackOverflow(T t) -> decltype(t.size() /* plus some decay */) { return t.size(); }

template<typename T>
auto JSchaubStackOverflow(T t) -> decltype(t.foobar() /* plus some decay */) { return t.foobar(); }
struct Metallica
{

    Metallica* foobar() const
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
};


int do_something() {
       JSchaubStackOverflow(std::vector<int>());
       JSchaubStackOverflow(Metallica());
       return 4;
}
[tej@archivbox ~]$ c++ -std=c++14 -pedantic test2.cc -c -o test2.o
[tej@archivbox ~]$ nm test2.o | grep JScha
0000000000000000 W _Z20JSchaubStackOverflowI9MetallicaEDTcldtfp_6foobarEET_
0000000000000000 W _Z20JSchaubStackOverflowISt6vectorIiSaIiEEEDTcldtfp_4sizeEET_
[tej@archivbox ~]$ nm -C test2.o | grep JScha
0000000000000000 W decltype (({parm#1}.foobar)()) JSchaubStackOverflow<Metallica>(Metallica)
0000000000000000 W decltype (({parm#1}.size)()) JSchaubStackOverflow<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >)
```

What you can see from this, is the decltype(whatever) can help us differentiate between symbols, it is part of the signature. But "auto" doesn't help us...
So if vector had both a foobar, and size method, both overloads of JSchaubStackOverflow would be mangled as *Z20JSchaubStackOverflowISt6vectorIiSaIiEEEDaT*
Now I'll leave to someone else to find to related section in ISO about signatures of template functions.

--EDIT--
I know it already has an accepted answer, but just for the record, here is a technical difficulty -- declarations without definitions:

```
[tej@archivbox ~]$ cat test2.cc

#include <vector>

template<typename T>
auto JSchaubStackOverflow(T t) -> decltype(t.size());

template<typename T>
auto JSchaubStackOverflow(T t) -> decltype(t.foobar());

struct Metallica
{

    Metallica* foobar() const
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
};


int do_something() {
       JSchaubStackOverflow(std::vector<int>());
       JSchaubStackOverflow(Metallica());
       return 4;
}
[tej@archivbox ~]$ c++ -std=c++14 -pedantic test2.cc -c -o test2.o
[tej@archivbox ~]$ nm -C test2.o | grep JScha
                 U decltype (({parm#1}.foobar)()) JSchaubStackOverflow<Metallica>(Metallica)
                 U decltype (({parm#1}.size)()) JSchaubStackOverflow<std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > >(std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >)
```

This means one can do the whole thing without function bodies. The template specializations would be given in another translation unit, but for this, the linker needs to find them... thus one can't overload on function body.

Comment: Can your `nm` handle demangling the symbols (i.e. `nm -C`)? If everything goes right the difference in the symbols is still apparent, but it’s more human-friendly. [edit: or if you can feed the output of `nm` through an up-to-date `c++filt` that works too]

Answer (score 1):

From [cppreference.com](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sfinae):

> Only the failures in the types and expressions in the immediate context of the function type or its template parameter types are SFINAE errors.
>
> If the evaluation of a substituted type/expression causes a side-effect such as instantiation of some template specialization, generation of an implicitly-defined member function, etc, errors in those side-effects are treated as hard errors.

Your first declaration causes implicit substitution of the return type, and therefore does not adhere to SFINAE